# How to solve illegal offset error in wordpress PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Our hosting provider has recently updated their PHP version and we're now facing the following issue.

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'items' in /home/unite-helpers.php on line 778

The code this relates to is as follows, which is already in single quotes:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'ut_recognized_google_fonts' ) ) {

function ut_recognized_google_fonts( $field_id = '' ) {

    if ( false === get_transient( 'ut_recognized_google_fonts' ) ) {

        $google_fonts = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( FW_WEB_ROOT . '/core/admin/assets/fonts/google_fonts.json' ) ), true );        

        set_transient( 'ut_recognized_google_fonts' , $google_fonts, 60 * 60 * 24 );

    } else {

        $google_fonts = get_transient( 'ut_recognized_google_fonts' );       

    }

    return apply_filters( 'ut_recognized_google_fonts' , $google_fonts['items'] , $field_id );

}

}
```

If anyone can shed some light on how to resolve this it would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: use is_array() and isset() methods for setting variables and arrays. Illegal offset error comes when you are not setting variable or arrays properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `$google_fonts['items']`, which isn't defined.

You could do:

```
$gf = isset($google_fonts['items']) ? $google_fonts['items'] : null;
return apply_filters( 'ut_recognized_google_fonts' , $gf );
```

Warning, check that "null" is a more or less logic value for that filter. But since you were passing an undefined value, I guess it would work.

You could also use `array_key_exists`, but since you are not handling nulls on any particular way, this is (*very* marginally) faster.

Comment: Awesome, it worked perfectly, thanks so much for your help with that.